# Nodejs mariadb INSERT INTO TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, insert, mariadb

what am i doing wrong?

```
const mariadb = require("mariadb");

(() => {
  setTimeout(async () => {
    console.log("connecting to db...");
    try {
      const pool = await mariadb.createPool({
        host: "localhost", //172.17.0.1
        user: "root",
        database: "gamifydb",
        port: "3306",
        password: "password"
      });
      const conn = await pool.getConnection();
      global.conn = conn;
      console.log("mariadb db connected");
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }, 1000);
})();
```

```
const achievement = {
    name: "lorem",
    user_id: "lorem",
    challenge_id:2,
    desc:"lorem"
}
```

```
exports.createAchievement = async achievement => {
  try {
    const response = await global.conn.query(
      "INSERT INTO achievements value (?,?,?,?);",
      Object.values(achievement)
    );
    console.log(response);
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};
```

**"(conn=1194, no: 1136, SQLState: 21S01) Column count doesn't match value count at row 1\nsql: INSERT INTO achievements value (?,?,?,?); - parameters:['lorem','lorem',2,'lorem']"
}**

Comment: This is a question where reading the error message carefully can lead you directly to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your table `achievements` has more than 4, or less than 4, columns.

Name the columns in your INSERT statement. Something like this might work

```
INSERT INTO achievements (name, user_id, challenge_id, desc)
VALUES (?,?,?,?);
```

Oh, and it's VALUES, not `value`.